# How to show pagination in git checkout or output to a file?

Tags: git, terminal, iterm2

I'm on a Mac El Capitan using iTerm2, is there a command to show/enable paging when using git checkout branchName or simply output the error/result that is displaying on the terminal screen to a file? Currently when I use git checkout branchname, it fills the whole screen and then at the very bottom it says, "**Please move or remove them before you can switch branches. Aborting.**" but I'm not sure what the start of the error is so I need a way to see at the very top of the message. I have tried git checkout branchname > error.log but nothing was captured in the log file. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`>error.log` will only redirect `stdout`, but the error is probably output to `stderr`, so either do `2>error.log` to redirect `stderr` to the file, or `&>error.log` to redirect both to the file. If the latter does not work, you are maybe not using Bash and `>error.log 2>&1` will do the same. (the order is important for the last one)

Comment: Git normally paginates almost all of its output, at least where it expects this could be needed. I guess this is a location where it does not paginate. Try to do `git log` to see whether pagination works at all.